# Mosquitto and simple Paho JS Client

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am trying to get a simple mqtt broker set up and access it from a web page. I have had pretty much 0 luck.

I've got mosquitto 2.0.14 downloaded and running. Here's my configuration file:

```
listener 1883
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

This generates the following log when I run `mosquitto -c mosquitto_conf -v`

```
1637948154: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
1637948154: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1637948154: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1637948154: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1637948154: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1637948154: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
```

Here's my html file, which I simply open in the browser. It uses Paho's js client.:

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var mqtt;
    var reconnectTimeout = 2000;
    var host = "192.168.1.94";
    var port = 9001;

    function onConnect() {
        console.log("Connected");
        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("hello");
        message.destinationName = "sensor1";
        mqtt.send(message);
    }

    function mqttConnect() {
        console.log("Connecting to " + host + ":" + port);
        mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, port, "clientjs");
        var options = {
            timeout: 3,
            onSuccess: onConnect,
        };

        mqtt.connect(options);
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <script>
        mqttConnect();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using a guide from this website: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/using-javascript-mqtt-client-websockets/

It errors out with the following console error in the browser:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9001/mqtt' failed
```

I have been having a hard time finding an updated tutorial that works. My ultimate goal is to create a react app that connects to an mqtt broker via websockets and receives messages to update state in redux.

Questions:
How do I get the js client to connect?
How do I set the host for mosquitto? Can I use a diff host like myhost.local or am I stuck using 127.0.0.1 or whatever I see when I run ipconfig (I'm on windows)?

Comment: When I change the host to `localhost` it works. But mosquitto log says `Sending CONNACK to clientjs (0,5)` and then immediately after that, `Client clientjs closed its connection.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `allow_anonymous true` to allow users to connect without supplying a username/password.

This is part of the set of changes introduced in v2.0 to improve the default security posture of mosquitto out of the box.

Comment: The total solution was a bit more complicated, but this is one step towards a solution. The next is not using Paho altogether because it has been abandoned. I'm using mqtt react hooks and am able to connect over websockets.